# How to refresh single section header's text in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I'm using a table view to display a checklist. Some views group list items by type. For these I display the type name with the item count in parentheses (e.g. "Things to do today (58)").

I want to refresh that string to reflect the updated count when the user deletes or completes an item.

This can be accomplished easily by setting the header's `textLabel` property and calling `setNeedsLayout()`. Problem is, it changes the appearance of the text.

Before (all caps default section title font, e.g. "THINGS TO DO TODAY (58)"):
[screenshot - before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGwhz.png)

After (no longer all caps, e.g. "Things to do today (58)"):
[screenshot - after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBWII.png)

Here's the code I'm using currently to refresh the header:

```
func refreshHeaderTitleForSection(_ section: Int) {
    if let header = tableView.headerView(forSection: section) {
      header.textLabel?.text = getHeaderTitleForSection(section)
      header.setNeedsLayout()
    } else {
      return
    }
  }
```

I'm calling `getHeaderTitleForSection()` to get the string for `titleForHeaderInSection` when the table view loads, so it should be the same. Is there a way to tell it to keep the default formatting without defining a custom header view?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your `getHeaderTitleForSection` method returns the non-uppercase string. `UITableView` automatically shows section headers in all uppercase regardless of what you return from `titleForHeaderInSection`.

The easiest solution is for you to force all uppercase when you update your header view.

```
header.textLabel?.text = getHeaderTitleForSection(section).uppercased()
```

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, yes that will work in this example. I should clarify though that I reuse this view in a few places throughout my app. The screenshots show its appearance as a standalone (full screen) view controller using a grouped table view. Sometimes it's containerized & not grouped & the headers aren't all caps. What I really want is to preserve the initial appearance of the text, just refresh the contents of the string.